# Should I drop the hyphen in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

> I bought a small cake, plus a lighter and a number one and number six
>   shaped candle.

The original words are *number-one shaped candle* and *number-six shaped candle*. Is it correct to drop the hyphen when used as in the sentence above?

Comment: One trouble is that they are numerals, not numbers, so don't bother about the rules for punctuating numbers. I think you do need hyphens - after *one* and *six*.

Comment: 'I bought a small cake; also, a lighter and two candles, one shaped like a number one and one shaped like a number six.' Stacked premodifiers ('number-six-shaped')  are unwieldy and should not be used where the presence or absence of a hyphen is a likely cause for concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes down to a matter of style and personal preference.

For example, the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) has specific rules regarding when to hyphenate and when not to, for a number of different situations concerning the use of numbers, here's an example (there are more in the linked chapter):

> *numbers, spelled out*
>
> Twenty-one through ninety-nine 
>   hyphenated; others open. See 
>   also fractions, simple..

But unless you are writing a formal paper (in which case I would check to see if there is any style guide in use which might specify a rule) you can use hyphenated or open according to your personal sense of style. The key is that you should be consistent with whichever option you choose and don't mix open with hyphenated for the same number in the same document.